# rails/jquery How to pass data from jquery to embedded ruby in js.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my view I have a select box pulling from ProductPrice model (a has_many relationship) for product pricing.

I am trying to get the price from the ProuductPrice model to update a span in the view with the price of the selected option.

```
view:

<label>Size</label>
<select id="volumeinfo" name="volumeinfo">
  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@product.prices, :id, :volume_info) %>
</select>

<span id="price"></price>



product_prices model

def volume_info
  "#{volume} #{unit}"
end



volumeinfo.js.erb

productid = $( "#volumeinfo" ).val()

$( "#volumeinfo" ).change(function() {
  // Possible to fetch productid from ProductPrice model?
  $("#price").text("<%= ProductPrice.find().price %>")
});
```

Comment: In your `.change` function, you'll need to do an `ajax` call to the server and then insert the return value into your `price` span.

Comment: You could add price attributes to your options when they are created and use jquery to get the price attribute from the selected option without needing another ajax request

Comment: ^ that's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to add the `data-price` attribute to your options:

`options_for_select(@product.map{ |product| [product.name, product.id, { 'data-price' => product.price }] })`

then use jquery to get the value of the `data-price` attribute from the selected option with something like:

`$("#volumeinfo").find("option:selected").attr("data-price)`

Using this method you wouldn't need to make any unnecessary ajax requests to get the price.